# How ampersand works in print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`print(2&3)` printed `2`. But want to understand how is it working?

```
print(2&3)
```

Output: `2`

```
print(7&8)
```

Output: `0`

```
print("a"&"b")

Exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Please some one help to understand how `&` is working in python.

Comment: it's a [bitwise-and operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). (and has nothing to do with print).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is a [bitwise and operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) : each bit of **the same rank** are *and evaluated*, if **both** bits are 1, the result **of that rank** is 1

Ranks are the position from right to left in a binary representation of a number.

```
0010
^^^^
||||
|||+-- rank 0
||+--- rank 1
|+---- rank 2
+----- rank 3
```

`2 & 3` can be translated, in binary as `0010 & 0011` :

```
  0010
& 0011
------
  0010
```

Result is `0010` which is 2 in decimal

`7 & 8` can be translated, in binary as `0111 & 1000` :

```
  0111
& 1000
------
  0000
```

Result is `0000` which is 0 in decimal